# How to input a value on a web form and store it as numeric in SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have the following code:

```
protected void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (intSlipID_srch.Text == "")
        lblStatus.Text = "Please enter a Slip ID.  ";
    string connection =
    WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["popeye_marina"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);

    // Clear text controls

    txtSlipLength.Text = string.Empty;
    txtSlipWidth.Text = string.Empty;
    txtCovered.Text = string.Empty;
    txtFee.Text = string.Empty;
    intDockID.Text = string.Empty;
    intBoatID.Text = string.Empty;

    // Create Update SQL string

    string insertSQL;
    insertSQL = "INSERT INTO slip (";
    insertSQL += "slip_length, slip_width, ";
    insertSQL += "covered, annual_fee, dock_id, boat_id) ";
    insertSQL += "VALUES (";
    insertSQL += "@slip_length, @slip_width, @covered, ";
    insertSQL += "@fee, @dockID, @boatID)";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertSQL, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@slip_length", txtSlipLength.Text);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@slip_width", txtSlipWidth.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@covered", txtCovered.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fee", txtFee.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dockID", intDockID.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@boatID", intBoatID.Text);
    int inserted = 0;
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        inserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        lblStatus.Text = inserted.ToString() + " record inserted.";
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        lblStatus.Text = "Error saving Slip.  ";
        lblStatus.Text += err.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

The target database column is numeric. When I run the web form and enter a numeric value, I get the error:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric

Can you tell me how to correct this error?

Comment: One (or more) of your columns are `numeric`, but you're passing it a string. Convert the values (for example, `fee` to a `decimal`)

Comment: the SQL Server is able to convert the content of the string to a numeric value just make sure that you don't pass  an empty string or a string containing white space or invalid chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's a two mistakes here,

first, why you clear the textbox before assign it to a new variable. it would always retrun a null string.

```
txtSlipLength.Text = string.Empty;
txtSlipWidth.Text = string.Empty;
txtCovered.Text = string.Empty;
//...
```

second is, you need to convert your value to an appropriate data type with your table.

ex:

```
//if your column is Decimal
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@slip_length", Convert.ToDecimal(txtSlipLength.Text));
//if your column is Integer
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@slip_length", Convert.ToInt32(txtSlipLength.Text));
//if your column is string (nvarchar, varchar, char, etc.) then you can use your code
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@slip_length", txtSlipLength.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which particular column but few of your table columns are numeric and passing them as string to DB will definitely cause casting/conversion error. For example:`annual_fee` you are passing it as text. rather convert to int and then passs it like

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fee", Convert.ToInt32(txtFee.Text));
```

Even Better, use the overload of `Add()` method like

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@fee", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtFee.Text));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a variable like `slip_length` is numeric and you pass a string for it, which is associated with nvarchar type. You could alleviate this is, like below:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@slip_length", decimal.Parse(txtSlipLength.Text));
```

However, you **have to pay attention** that if `txtSlipLength.Text` cannot be parsed to a decimal, an exception would be thrown. You could tackle with this with many ways. At first you have to set up a validation scheme and if and only if the criteria you have defined would be met, to proceed in data persistence. Then you could use the proactive edition of `Parse` methods, `TryParse`.

Comment: @Trevor, could you please share the exception message? Thanks

Comment: When I try cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@slip_length", decimal.Parse(txtSlipLength.Text)); I get Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Source Error:


Line 201:        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertSQL, con);
Line 202:        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@slip_length", txtSlipLength.Text);
Line 203:        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@slip_length", decimal.Parse(txtSlipLength.Text));
Line 204:        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@slip_width", txtSlipWidth.Text);
Line 205:        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@covered", txtCovered.Text);

Comment: @Trevor a problem at all :) So this is the case that I mentioned above. The parse there fails. So it's up to how you will proceed. Is `slip_length` a required field or not? In other words, can it take a NULL as a value? What is the value of `txtSlipLength.Text`?

Comment: Christos, can I ask you a follow up?  It now works when a value is entered. I have defined the column as Numeric, Nulls allowed in the database.  But when  the input field is blank and I try to insert a null into the database,  I get errors again.  What is the best way of handling that?